# how to add credits each month with rules?

Tags: commerce, rules

How do I add commerce credits to a specific type of user the first in every month? I cant seem to find a date field in rules-->add rule-->events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Rules Example](http://drupal.org/project/rules_example) which is an example module showing how to integrate custom module with rules.

You can add a new parameter (e.g. condition - check if this is first day of the month) and perform all checks/actions you need there.